# Kernel 3.x & Kernel 4.x Netfilter hook

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel

Depending on the kernel documentation, kernel change the way of calling nf_hook

kernel 3.x

```
static inline int nf_hook(u_int8_t pf, unsigned int hook, struct sk_buff *skb,struct net_device *indev, struct net_device *outdev,int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
```

kernel 4.x

```
static inline int NF_HOOK(uint8_t pf, unsigned int hook, struct net *net, struct sock *sk,struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *in, struct net_device *out,int (*okfn)(struct net  *, struct sock *, struct sk_buff *))
```

I have 2 questions

1. Should i call NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT in a hook of NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING , because i want to send packets to packet sender while i am reading packet in pre routing
2. Should i use Null for struct net *net, struct sock *sk,struct  when i am sending packet to the outside ? Or how should i create a new socket and declare net object.